# iOS7: How do I find a location in Maps and assign it as the location on a calendar entry?

Tags: calendar, geolocation, maps

I like that the Calendar now allows assigning a location to an entry which can then be opened in Maps.

Unfortunately it appears to be confined to locations assigned to contacts - which make sense if you for instance need to meet at somebodys - but now I had the need to pinpoint a location on the map which I do not intuitively map to a contact (a cinema actually) and use that as the meeting location, and could not figure out how.

The search function in Maps found the cinema and allowed me to select it to see it on the map.  The pinhead was red and I could assign it to a contact, but not to a calendar entry.

Is this doable, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Tap the pinhead, click SHARE, click COPY TO CLIPBOARD, paste into location. It works for me, some may think too many steps, but it's okay!

Comment: I cannot locate the "Copy to clipboard" action.  Could you add a screenshot of where you found it?